# In a Cypress test, increment function doesn't work which needs to increments the number each time?

Tags: javascript, cypress

In a Cypress test.

I am calling a simple increment function `getNumber()` which needs to increment the number each time when the function is called.

This number is required to attach to the name of the text field while creating a form i.e. **unique form name**.

While running the test, it actually returns `1`, but running the second time, it still returns `1` instead of `2`.

How can I achieve this or is there any better way of doing this?

Someone, please advise a better way of achieving this?

Code:

```
const getNumber = (() => {
      var count = 0;
      return () => ++count;
    })();
  cy.wrap({ number: getNumber }).invoke('number')
           .then(number => {
               const someNum = number;
               cy.log(someNum);              
              cy.visit("https://sometestsite.com/createForm")
             cy.get('#SomeIdOfTextField').type('Form_Name'+someNum)
        })
```

Comment: I believe each test run will clear all memory of `var`'s and `const`'s. You would need to loop the field check within the field.

Comment: @thisiskelvin: I have tried that, the problem with that approach is that, the test will run for the whole loop count in one go. Say, if I have set the loop count to 10, then the test will run 10 times incrementing these values. I don't want to run 10 time in one go.

Comment: I have tried cy.pause() at the end of each loop run, but still, that is not a good option. If there are other tests to run, the pause() will be a problem I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are redeclaring `count` every time you call `getNumber()`.  Move the `count` declaration outside of the function like this:

```
var count = 0;
const getNumber = (() => {
      return () => ++count;
    })();
  cy.wrap({ number: getNumber }).invoke('number')
           .then(number => {
               const someNum = number;
               cy.log(someNum);              
              cy.visit("https://sometestsite.com/createForm")
             cy.get('#SomeIdOfTextField').type('Form_Name'+someNum)
        })
```

Comment: I will give a try soon and reply back